# unable to load jekyll on server

Tags: jekyll, blogs

This is my _config.yml file for jekyll server. The ip written in url is of my server IP. When I run Jekyll serve it gives me this message

```
Configuration file: /root/cloudadic/_config.yml
            Source: .
       Destination: ./_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.507 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '.'
Configuration file: /root/cloudadic/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000
```

_config.yml

```
 # Site settings
    title: ACBD
    description: "A minimal blog template, build with Jekyll."
    url: "http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:4000/"

    # Build settings
    baseurl:  # Change this to your relative path (ex: /blog), or leave just a /
    markdown: kramdown
    source: .
    destination: ./_site
    permalink: /:title
    paginate: 8
    paginate_path: /page:num/

    # Default values
    defaults:
      -
        scope:
          path: ""
          type: "posts"
        values:
          layout: "post"

    # Custom variables
    version: "1.1.0"

    # Options
    custom_header: false
    custom_nav_footer: false
    reverse: false

    gems:
        - jekyll-sitemap
        - jekyll-paginate
```

But when I try to visit http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:4000/ this, the blog doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

> Server address: `http://127.0.0.1:4000`

If you want your server to respond at `http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:4000/`, you have to set `host` in `_config.yml` ([see doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)).

```
host: XXX.XX.XX.XXX
```